# HSQLDB clustering/replication support?

Tags: replication, hsqldb, cluster-computing

Does HSQLDB support replication or clustering. I found an age old experimental feature for HSQLDB replication.
see http://www.jgroups.org/hsqldbr.html and www.jgroups.org/hsqldbr/design.pdf 
but it seems this feature never made its way to hsqldb.

Does anyone know what is the current status of this feature and whether or not hsqldb support replication/clustering?

Edit: We used HA-JDBC and found it to be quite useful for our need. Initially, I thought HA-JDBC is a dead project because there were no releases for the past 3 years, but it being maintained in a SVN repository and new features are being added in GIT repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is supported by add-ons C-JDBC and HA-JDBC as listed on this page. Replication and clustering has many variations and these software package cover different feature sets.

http://hsqldb.org/web/hsqlUsing.html